# Matrix `sum` in MATLAB giving counterintuitive answer

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I am getting the following answer in MATLAB as solution of a linear system of equations

`ans =
   1.0e+05 *
   2.1736 + 0.0000i
  -1.0868 - 2.1408i
  -1.0868 + 2.1408i`

when i do `sum(ans)` it gives `1` as the answer but when i physically add  them it turns to be `0`

What am i doing wrong? Cannot figure out at all

Comment: You're not seeing all the digits. Use `format long` and then check the answer to see more digits.

Comment: @SardarUsama You were right. The `1.0e+05` factor makes expressing the matrix elements to be in `long` format necessary.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra, you can add an answer so it can help someone else.

Comment: @Bebs Sure will do that